# MySQL - how do you rewrite this to work with ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY

Tags: mysql

How do you rewrite this MySQL query to work with ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY

`SELECT filename FROM documentdb GROUP BY filename ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 10`

Where `documentdb` is a table that contains several columns, including both `timestamp` and `filename`...

Comment: A lot of different `timestamp` values matched the same `filename` value... what `timestamp` value must be used for sorting?

Answer (score 1):

Since each filename can appear more than once in documentdb, you need to decide which timestamp you want to order them by.

For instance, you could do:

```
select filename
from documentdb
group by filename
order by max(timestamp) desc
limit 10
```

or

```
select filename
from documentdb
group by filename
order by min(timestamp) desc
limit 10
```

The original query was ambiguous about which timestamp for a given filename to compare.

Interestingly, the mariadb implementation of only_full_group_by does not object to the original query, at least in 10.5; this seems like a bug, which per https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-24239 should be addressed in 10.6.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a0710b7b47840ea734cf408201c2f0e4)

Answer (score 0):

Using `MAX` over timestamp column in `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT filename FROM documentdb GROUP BY filename ORDER BY MAX(timestamp) DESC LIMIT 10
```